# How to check windows service status using .Net 6 web application?

Tags: windows-services, .net-6.0

I need to find a way to monitor the status of a list of Windows services over HTTP using .Net 6 web application.

All I really need to be able to do is display the service name and its status ('Started' / 'Stopped').

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the status of a windows web service directly AFAIK. I would create a controller for that and call methods on the controller that will return the status of the specified windows service (on the specified server, if that is also a requirement).